# index and match 2 criteria with COUNTIF

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, countif

I know many questions have been asked for using INDEX and MATCH with criteria and returning a unique list without duplicates. And I have that much working. But I ran into a problem.

Here is my data:

[image]

Here is the list i uniquely generate:

[image]

The problem is, it skips Tom Smith because it thinks that Smith, Tom is a duplicate so it removes it. This is a problem. Here is the formula I'm using:

`=INDEX('C:\path\to\file\[schedule sample.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$108, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($A$2:A2, 'C:\path\to\file\[schedule sample.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$108), 0))`

how do I prevent the problem of excluding names if only column B matches?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a concatenation of all relevant columns for the comparison.

For the given example, this result in rather complicated formulas, I am afraid. That's why Excel has a function in the filtering where it does exactly this (check 'unique').

With formulas, you would need to put into E2 `=B2&'|'&C2&'|'&D2` and copy it down.
Then you run your whole copy-to-another-sheet logic on the E2 column only, and in the target sheet, split the string again at the `'|'` into three columns.

Depending on your limitations and requirements, it could be much easier to instead simply run the 'unique' filter on that E column, and get the result in the F column for wahtever you want to do with it. This is an action everytime data changes though; if you want it to work 'magically' through the formulas, you will need the more complex approach.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to lay this out. I get what you're saying about concatenation, I'll look how to incorporate it. I am well aware of the unique filter function but wanted something more automated.